# How to open Control Panel's System information using CMD

Tags: batch-file, controlpanel

I want to create a batch file that will open "Control Panel\System and Security\System"

I'm using Windows 10 and the "This PC" is not searchable in cortana, I often check system archetecture by right clicking This PC>properties but I want to do it in Batch (.bat file) and it does'nt work

Batch Command: start "" "Control Panel\System and Security\System" & exit

A prompt pops up: "Windows cannot find 'Control Panel\System and Security\System'. make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again."

Comment: This is not a programming question. Ask on https://superuser.com. Traditional control panel items are `*.cpl` in `system32`. So typing `sysdm.cpl` will start it.

Comment: @Noodles `sysdm.cpl` (at least on Windows 10) opens the System Properties, not Control Panel\System and Security\System. IMO this is on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've been wondering why control panels haven't caught up with ms-settings.  I saw an app that added protocol handlers for control panels to support deep linking... guess it depends how much work you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is the `control` command. You can find more info [Here](https://www.lifewire.com/command-line-commands-for-control-panel-applets-2626060)

Try `control /name Microsoft.System`.

Comment: It worked! I tried `start control /name Microsoft.System` thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Operating Systems architecture, directly in a batch file without opening up a GUI box:

You can either use the built in system variables, to retrieve either, `x86` or `x64`:

```bat
@Set "OSA=x%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"
@If %OSA%==x86 If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set "OSA=x64"
@Echo %OSA%&Pause
```

Or if you wanted just `32` or `64`

```bat
@If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2% Equ 86 (If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (Set "OSA=64")Else Set "OSA=32")Else Set "OSA=64"
@Echo %OSA%&Pause
```

You could even just view it in a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), *(Command Prompt)*, window with:

```bat
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2% Equ 86 (If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (Echo 64-bit)Else Echo 32-bit)Else Echo 64-bit
```

You could also use a built in tool, like [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic), to retrieve either, `32` or `64`:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('WMIC OS Get OSArchitecture')Do Set /A "OSA=%%A" 2>Nul
@Echo %OSA%&Pause
```

Comment: This is a good info! This will be a good addition to my batch.. it prints desired result just I wanted.. Thanks!

Comment: @JulesIvanGaray, is it not what you would consider a more suitable solution to "check system archetecture"..."but I want to do it in Batch (.bat file)" than `control /name Microsoft.System`

Comment: @JulesIvanGaray, please consider revising your choice of accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar question and found a partial answer;
in cmd, type "start ms-settings:"
this starts the Settings app in Win10. What if I'm trying to open a specific page within the Settings app, specifically the "Accounts"?
i tried typing "control /name Microsoft.System" into cmd and this returned the older version of the app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).